# Recipe - ingredients database in Entity Framework ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

This will create two tables "Ingredient" and "Recipe" and an additional table for many-to-many mapping.

```
public class DC : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
}

public class Recipe {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

Question: I want to include additional column "quantity" in the third mapping table that will be created by Entity Framework. How to make that possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you've got some extra information, I suspect it won't really count as a mapping table any more - it's not *just* a many-to-many mapping. I think you should just model it as another table:

```
public class Ingredient {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RecipePart> RecipeParts { get; set; }
}

public class RecipePart {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Ingredient { get; set; }
    public Recipe { get; set; }
    // You'll want to think what unit this is meant to be in... another field?
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Recipe {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RecipePart> Parts { get; set; }
}
```

So now you don't really have a many-to-many mapping - you have two ordinary many-to-one mappings. Do you definitely need to "ingredient to recipes" mapping exposed in your model at all? If you want to find out all the recipes which use a particular ingredient, you could always do a query such as:

```
var recipies = DB.Recipies.Where(r => r.Parts
                                       .Any(p => p.Ingredient == ingredient));
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but since I'm new to Entity Framework, I've got a question about RecipePart class you provided. Should it be: "public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; };" or "public int IngredientID { get; set; }"?

Comment: @Acute: I couldn't say, I'm afraid - I don't know enough about EF myself.